# Do the "StreamWriter.WriteLine()" function need to "lock()"?

Tags: c#

i develop a class to write logs. it writes with "StreamWriter.WriteLine()" function.

```
logStream.WriteLine(msgWrite);
logStream.Flush();
```

some different threads use this class to write logs, in one text file(The log file is common for all threads) do it need to lock() function?

should i change my code?

```
lock(syncObj)
{
    logStream.WriteLine(msgWrite);
    logStream.Flush();
}
```

please help me.

Comment: Must have been this link in duplicate probably: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591297/thread-safe-streamwriter-c-sharp-how-to-do-it-2

Comment: Also relevant: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/08/12/blocking-collection-and-the-producer-consumer-problem.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap your writer in [`TextWriter.Synchronized`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.synchronized(v=vs.110).aspx) which, as that document suggests, ensures that all resulting write operations are performed in a thread-safe manner.

Aside from that, yes, you could just use a `lock` to do it, but when there's built-in functionality like this I tend to prefer it.

A quick-and-dirty implementation could look something like this:

```
public static class Logs
{
    static Logs()
    {
        _Writer = TextWriter.Synchronized(new StreamWriter(path));
    }

    private static TextWriter _Writer;

    static void LogLine(string line)
    {
        _Writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: `WriteLine`'s thread safety is implementation-dependent, but if you have a look at the current source for `StreamWriter` and its base (`TextWriter`), it's definitely not a good idea to call `WriteLine(string)` concurrently as it ultimately writes the string's characters one by one in a loop.